# Wordpress Register options when plugin is activated

Tags: php, wordpress, settings

I want to register an option when my plugin is activated to be used in the settings page.

My code is like this:

```
function jpsNews_activate_plugin() {
    // REGISTER SETTINGS
    register_setting( 'jps_settings_group', 'jps_test');
    ...
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'jpsNews_activate_plugin');
```

When i go to the database and search for that option, nothing is found. What am i missing? Can i do it like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option will only get stored to the database after you go to the setting pane and submit new values.

You have to remember that in Wordpress - like in any PHP application - stuff gets loaded only when a code runs to load it. And the settings API allows you to create settings pages for the current admin page being used - the `register_setting()` method doesn't "register your new settings in the database" or something, it just displays the settings to the admin if the admin is currently in the admin screen and looking at the settings page!

The correct way to create new settings is to register the settings under the `admin_init` action, which happens just before the admin pages are shown to the admin. See [the `register_settings()` documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) for a simple example on how to do this correctly.

Comment: So, i cant make it on plugin activation? I've also tried to make it like this: `add_action( 'admin_init', 'jps_settings' )`; and then, `function jps_settings() {...}` but nothig happend

Comment: As I've explained in my answer, Wordpress doesn't have a "settings repository" where you can add your settings and Wordpress will load them - settings are added at runtime when displaying the admin screens.

Comment: If you've used the correct action, you still won't see your settings in the database - as I've mentioned in my answer, just adding the settings and loading the admin page is not enough to create the setting in the database - you have to actually put in some value with the admin screen and save it. To do that you also need to draw the UI for the setting, which you didn't show in your code example, so I assume you didn't. I suggest reading up on the settings API, and also you can review this code I've written: https://github.com/con-tools/wordpress-plugin/blob/master/con-troll/options.php

Comment: tks, that helped me to get started =)