# Activating registration by coding in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a user login page for the WordPress theme that I have designed, which will be displayed if WordPress registration is enabled through the settings.
Like the picture below:
[WordPress registration option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frmwC.png)

But since a user using my theme might forget to enable this option, I'm looking for a piece of code that I can put in the `functions.php` file to fix this problem.

The code I was able to find for this purpose is as follows:

```
// Enable user registration
function enable_registration() {
    return true; // false for disable
}
add_filter('registration_errors', 'enable_registration');
add_filter('wp_signup_location', 'enable_registration');
```

This code activates the registration in WordPress, but when the user wants to enter his account, he is faced with the message: (**Registration is not enabled for new users**).

All I want is for the wordpress registration option to be enabled and not allowed to disable the wordpress registration option until the user disables my theme.

---

**Edit:**

Friends, I am looking for a piece of code that can activate the option (**Membership**) that I have specified in the image.

Enabling only WordPress registration does not solve my problem and I have to enable this option by putting a code in the `functions.php` file.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is possible through a plugin or theme. It would be insecure to allow a plugin/theme to change a setting that toggles the registration setting.

Comment: This issue is related to the theme designed by myself, so people who use my theme must accept the condition that WordPress registration must be active forever. There are many plugins that have this feature, now I want to add this code to my theme so that I don't have to use a separate plugin.

Comment: Do you know of any example plugins that have this feature?

Comment: For example, the **Profile** **Builder** plugin and also a similar question like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910380/wordpress-register-options-when-plugin-is-activated

Comment: Why did you delete your post from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77101447/activating-wordpress-registration-through-functions-php and repost it?

Comment: Because I did not have a sample code and my question was completely incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

In the WordPress database, the `users_can_register` option in `wp_options` table contains the setting for "Anyone can register"

You can trigger that option to update after a theme change with this code:

```php
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'theme_activation_update_option' );

function theme_activation_update_option () {
    update_option( 'users_can_register', 1 );
}
```

But as a huge caveat, it's not a good idea to trigger this from a theme because it can result in security issues for the site owner.

Comment: I tested your code but the registration mode is still disabled.

Comment: Or better to say, registration is enabled, but there is still a message to log in (Registration is not enabled for new users).

Comment: Is there a way to enable only the registration option?

Comment: Just to confirm, do you want the login page (/wp-login.php) to default to the register page (wp-login.php?action=register)?

Comment: As I have shown in the picture, the option check (**Membership**) must be activated, otherwise the login page I designed will not be loaded. Your code activates the registration correctly, but I have a problem logging in and it shows me the usual message. Only if the (**Membership**) option is enabled from the WordPress settings, my problem is solved. Thank you very much for your time so far.